# User authorization check with Express, Prisma and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, express, prisma, routing-controllers

How can you check user authorization with `Express`, `Routing-controllers`, `Prisma` and `Postgres` stack?

e.g. check if a request is the owner of the post to delete the post

Do you always need to call `db` twice to check if user is the author? e.g. `getPost` to check if `id` matches then `deletePost`